# String program crash whenever i use a for loop

Tags: c

Im trying to make a program that works like atoi, you enter a number in a string, and it convert the ascii value to an int, for that I make a while loop to take the dimension of the number, but whenever I try to use a for loop next to that while program output is nothing, doesnt matter what that for is

If I delete the for loop the program works fine, why does that happen?

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int cont = 0, a, array[10];
  char *string;
  printf("Insert a number: ");
  scanf("%s", string);
  
  while (string[cont] != 0) {
    printf("%d\t", string[cont] - 48);
    array[cont] = string[cont] - 48;
    cont++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("bruh\n");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to multiply the value of array[i] x 10 X times and then add it, I thought I'd do a for to go through the number of numbers the array has and multiply it by 10 X times in a while loop

Answer (score 2):

`string` does not point to valid memory. As such, trying to scan into it with `scanf` puts you in the realm of undefined behavior.

You need to either automatically or dynamically allocate memory for that character array. Something like:

```
char string[1024];
scanf("%1023s", string);
```

Using the `%1023s` specifier indicates a maximum width so that a buffer overflow does not occur. You should also check that `scanf` returns `1` to indicate that one value was successfully read.

Comment: It worked, Thanks! but why does that happen exactly? As long as it does not exit the while loop, it could perform any function within it.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" is exactly what it promises on the cover. The program _might_ scan in a string and work on it. Or it might _not_. Compile with warnings on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `value` to accumulate the sum of the digits. Was it `a`?

Also here

```
 int cont = 0, a, array[10];
 char *string;
```

you forgot to make `string` point to `array` as in

```
  char array[10];
  char *string = array;
```

so your pointer is not valid. And `string` should be `char[10]`

Another consideration is the signal. The array size is ok since `INT_MAX` is `2147483647` and has 10 digits, so it is safe to use `9` and the final `NULL` in the input string with no overflow or underflow POSSIBLE: from -999,999,999 to 999,999,999 ALL VALUES fits in an `int`.

Note that `scanf()` is buffered anyway until reading the `'\n'` so you are doing two loops: one until `'\n'` inside `'scanf'` and another until `'0'` in the `while`. And you still have the problem of filtering the digits from the string.

See this alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n_dig = 0;
  int sig = 1;
  int value = 0;
  // may have a signal
  printf("Insert a number (optional sign + up to 9 digits): ");
  int ch = fgetc(stdin);
  if (ch == '-')
    sig = -1;
  else if (ch == '+')
    sig = 1;
  else if (ch < '0')
    return 0;
  else if (ch > '9')
    return 0;
  else
    n_dig = 1, value = ch - '0';
  // '\n' ends all
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')
  {
    if (ch < '0' || ch > '9') break;
    value = (10 * value) + (ch - '0');
    n_dig += 1;
    if (n_dig == 9) break;
  };
  if (n_dig == 0) return -1;
  printf("Decimal value is %d\n", sig * value);
  return 0;
}
```

Differences

- a single loop using fgetc()
- a signal is ok, `+` or `-`
- input of only a signal returns error
- any non-digit exits the loop
- goes up to 9 digits and a signal

Comment: It seems unlikely the OP's mistake involved forgetting to initialize `string` to point to `array` given that `string` is of type `char *` and `array` is an array of ints.